# distinguish between click on a table row and on its text

Tags: html-table

I want to catch a click on a row of a table, but 2 actions based on where it was clicked:

- the 'empty space' of 1st column or any other column --> select that row
- the 'text' of 1st column --> do something based on that text (example, update that table with list of all staffs)

Note, there are multiple tables in the page, I need to catch the correct table object for updating.

The simple code (1 table) is below.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    table {
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    td, th {
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 8px;
    }
    
    tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #dddddd;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h2>HTML Table</h2>
    
    <table id="aTable">
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    <script>
      const tbl=document.getElementById("aTable");
      // click on a row, except on 'text' of 1st column
      tbl.onclick = (e) => {
        // set row = selected
      }
      // click on 'text' of 1st column
      // update the table with new data based on the 'text' of 1st column
    
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your text in `span`s and then handle event separate for span and th.

```html
<tr>
        <th><span>Company</span></th>
</tr>
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll("table tr").forEach(el=>el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // row clicked
})

document.querySelectorAll("table span").forEach(el=>el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // text clicked
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, can I catch the object table too, and clicked rowIndex? 
As I need to to update that table

Comment: In the same way as above you can handle any events on any components. You just need to specific which elements you want to get in querySelector. Selectors work in the same way as in css.